# Can we please use total score of the posts in meta participation instead of their number?

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta

The way how [meta participation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation) is calculated is explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149097/165773):

> Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits).

While above has a definite benefit of being simple, it looks way too simple. Suggest to change it to use total score of the posts instead of their number.

Using total score instead of number of posts is not much more complicated and I think it is even somewhat *simpler* to explain. Current way suggests that posts at +100 and -1 are equally valuable contributions which seems to be really [hard to grok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) (at least to me).

The way how system currently measures participation sends conflicting signals to voters. On one hand it suggests that voting is important, as important as posting, editing, commenting, okay. But on the other hand it sounds like it is only important to mechanically click the voting arrows, as if content being voted doesn't matter, as if it doesn't even matter if one votes up or down.

It's probably not the most important feature request out there but as an active [voter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters) I am not quite comfortable with the way how things work now.

Comment: alternatively, an explanation of why it would be better to keep things as they are now would also be appreciated. My reasoning in favor of change could have missed something

Comment: It is measuring **participation**, not how much others liked your posts. To foster debate, score should *not* be a factor in how much you participate.

Comment: So, as an active voter, your participation *is* accurately measured. The more you vote, the more you participate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "it is only important to mechanically click the voting arrows, as if content being voted doesn't matter, as if it doesn't even matter if one votes up or down"? I understand the idea of measuring participation, but I am find it difficult to figure why this way is accurate

Comment: I fail to see how including post scores is going to help *you* as a voter. It is your overall commenting, posting, voting and editing behaviour that puts you (rightly) at the top.

Comment: You as a voter *don't have a score*. Did you rather have that the system only measure your upvotes? We already have top tag answerers; that's where score is measured. But one popular question or answer does not mean you are participating more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it will help me as a voter by ensuring that system takes into account content / contributions I vote on (currently it's not the case, system even ignores whether I vote up or down). _Mechanically_, it may lower "participation" value for voters (by rebalancing things a bit in favor of posters) but I can't see reasons why this could be a bad thing

Comment: But receiving votes is **not participation**. I can sit here passively and let the votes roll in.

Comment: if this is **not participation**, I would appreciate a compelling explanation for that. As I wrote, it's hard to me to grok how "posts at +100 and -1 are equally valuable contributions"

Comment: Because being wrong has value too. You are still *participating*. The unvoiced opinion has no value to the community.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wrt "one popular question or answer", worth noting that after 60 days such a post won't count for participation. Unlike at main sites, one can't make a hit and accumulate votes on it forever. Participation in this sense is much different from reputation (FWIW this seems fair to me)

Comment: "But receiving votes is not participation" surely it is? Up votes means I helped someone with my answer or question, or someone additionally thought it was good/valuable and so upvoted me. Arguably a cap is needed, but why not have votes calculate into your net participation up to a point (like 5 net votes per Q or A)

Comment: @James No, it clearly isn't. Participation means taking an action. When you **post** an answer, that is the participation (counted once). If 100 people vote on it, **they** have each participated (once). It doesn't mean you have participated 101 times.

Comment: @AndrewMedico these 100 people who voted on some post, _how_ did they participate if system seems to ignore on what posts they voted and even whether they voted up or down. I would appreciate an explanation of this - as I wrote, it feels as if just the fact on mechanically clicking voting arrows is what counts

Comment: They participated by expressing their opinion on a post. It doesn't matter if they agreed or disagreed, or whether the post ended up with a positive or negative score. They added information to the system by voting.

Comment: @AndrewMedico "Participation means taking an action" What about *inactive participation*. I don't disagree with your logic, and while I agree *specifically* it is not *active participation*, I am still participating in that I am helping someone from my question or answer. The vote itself is not my participation, as I did nothing actively - the voter did, however the fact my Q or A helped someone is my continuing to participate (indirectly, inactively, or otherwise). The only way to recognise my *inactive participation* of my Q or A being useful is by *the vote* being on *my* Q or A.

Comment: @James Your "inactive participation" is recognized through badges and tag scores.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yes. I wasn't pointing out what the site *actually* gives me participation rewards for, just logically/hypothetically what is defined as *inactive participation*.

Comment: @James: 'inactive participation' is a contradiction in terms though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  "*'inactive participation' is a contradiction in terms*" Yeah it probably is. I was using the word "participation" as Stack uses it when referring to rewards/rep based on our actions. Whatever you want to label it, the point is I have an answer somewhere on Stack, someone reads it and gets use from it. I therefore have added value to the site. I have helped someone out, given someone a resolve to their issue, question, or predicament. I was inactive when it happened, however I still "helped" (so I assisted, inactively) which is fundamentally what rewards/rep are for.

Comment: @James: sure, but the ranking of users by participation clearly uses a different definition, and *I am fine with that definition*. We could tweak the relative weight of the 4 metrics perhaps, but the ranking is based *entirely* on your actual active participation, not on what others think about your post.

Comment: @James: And Meta is far more about discussion and consensus, a very different voting pattern from the main site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "*but the ranking is based entirely on your actual active participation*" - I get rep from my answers/questions when I'm not participating. I'm not even on-line at the time, I'm painting a ceiling...

Comment: @James: *Exactly*! So why should you be ranked higher than, say, Gnat, who is here voting, commenting, editing and answering?

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW Gnat's (voter's) concern is that system appears to ignore what they vote on and even whether they vote up or down. Idea of welcoming any post is rather hard to explain from the perspective of someone who picks what to vote on and how to vote, and it feels particularly weird when coupled with idea that vote is as important as other actions, making it feel that it's not voting that's important but mechanically clicking up/down arrows

Comment: @MartijnPieters I never said anyone should be ranked higher, just that my (ahem) inactive participation still adds value and therefore I should still gain rep. Gnat should get ranking based on his activity, as should I for my activity I performed in the past, and then additional ranking for votes on my answer because it is still offering value to the site and users (albeit it perhaps less ranking than active participation, but that's a whole new debate..).

Comment: @James: the ranking is already constrained to the last 60 days; why should posts you contributed outside that window count? Again, this is about *active participation*, not having contributed a popular retort somewhere. We already reward you with badges for that kind of thing. Past posts are not participation, however much someone appreciated your answer.

Comment: "*why should posts you contributed outside that window count*" - Why shouldn't it? Also, other than "because we need a line drawn somewhere", why 60 days? Why not 80, or 160, or 7? "*Past posts are not participation*" - No, they're not specifically due to the definition of that word, as I agreed previously, but an answer which gave someone benefit is just *as beneficial to the site and its users as the user who is doing nothing more than a single mouse click on an arrow* - surely? It benefited the user who clicked the arrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absence of answers and [rather anemic voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/274807/timeline) seems to indicate that this request is generally considered not important enough to bother.

For the sake of completeness, there were couple of arguments against the proposed change laid out in comments. One that looks most compelling to me ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274807/can-we-please-use-total-score-of-the-posts-in-meta-participation-instead-of-thei#comment107404_274807), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274807/can-we-please-use-total-score-of-the-posts-in-meta-participation-instead-of-thei#comment107414_274807)) is:

> To foster debate, score should *not* be a factor in how much you participate... being wrong has value too. You are still *participating*. The unvoiced opinion has no value to the community.

<sub>As a proponent of the change, I am certainly interested to <strike>trash</strike> counter above argument. But frankly, I could not find a way to do this, even though I tried.</sub>